# Добавление контролов из OpenGL.Net в панель элементов

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, visual-studio-2015

Доброго времени суток!
Используя NuGet установил в пустой проект (winforms, .net 4.6) OpenGL.Net (0.3.2).

Попытался добавить из dll библиотек в папке "packages" контролы на панель элементов (создал новую чтоб без путаницы), на что получал сообщение: *в этих библиотеках нет контролов которые можно добавить на эту панель*.

Аналогично было и с SharpGL библиотекой. Бинарников в репозиториях на github я не нашел. Альтернативных способов их получить (без лишних хитростей) не знаю.

**Вопрос**: как добавить контролы или как полноценно пользоваться библиотекой **OpenGL.Net** в Visual Studio 2015 (в DesignTime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, вы установили основной пакет для `OpenGL` вместо конкретного `OpenGL.Net.WinForms`:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenGL.Net.WinForms/

---

*Обновление*

В некоторых случаях подобная проблема решается путем перетаскивая .dll непосредственно в панель элементов

Comment: я установил оба этих пакета. (полагаю что между ними есть зависимость). Так или иначе, ни в одной из скачанных NuGet'ом библиотек нету доступных контролов (OpenGL.Net.WinForms.0.3.2 + OpenGL.Net.0.3.2).

Comment: Достаточно установить специфический пакет, основной есть в зависимостях. Только что проверил в `OpenGL.Net.WinForms.dll` действительно есть `glControl`.

Comment: @Новичок вы можете написать как добавляете контрол?

Comment: Кликаю правой кнопкой по вкладке панели элементов, потом пункт "Выбрать элементы...", перехожу во вкладку "Компоненты .Net Framework" и после прогрузки нажимаю на кнопку "Обзор" и выбираю библиотеку скачанную NuGet'ом (в папке packages рядом с проектом)

Comment: ![скрин ошибки](http://savepic.ru/12336145.png)

Comment: Все верно. Тогда не знаю - у меня работает. Попробую поискать информацию.

Comment: @Новичок а если попробовать перетащить .dll в панель элементов?

Comment: Перетаскивание помогло. Спасибо! Добавьте пожалуйста информацию в свой ответ. Возможно это поможет другим пользователям ресурса!